# How to implement Component sharing in different modules in Angular 7 while using lazy loading?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am working on upgrading existing Angular 4 project to Angular 7.I have implemented lazy loading.Everything is working fine, but at one issue I have strucked.A single component has been used multiple times for different routes in Angular 4 project.Since I am converting the project into Angular 7,I have divided the components into different modules.So,on using the same component in 2 different router modules, I am getting the error of 
"is part of the declarations of 2 modules"

How to use same component in different router modules in angular 7?

Comment: The same way as in every version of angular: by declaring the component in only one (shared) module, and importing that one (shared) module in all modules where you need it. https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules

Comment: i have to use the shared component in different router modules for navigation. how to use that component in router module? i have imported the shared module in module.ts of every module.

Comment: The way I explained in my previous comment, and the doc I linked to explains. If you think you have done that, and still have a problem, then ask why you get an error and post all the relevant code.